Convergence a.e. plus convergence of $L^1$ norms implies convergence in $L^1$
Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset L^1(\mu)$ is such that:

$f_n \to f \in L^1(\mu)$ a.e.
$ \int_A | f_n | \ \mathrm{d} \mu \to \int_A |f| \ \mathrm{d} \mu$

Then, is it true that $\int_A |f_n - f| \ \mathrm{d}\mu \to 0$?
I have managed to prove the claim under the additional assumption that $\mu(A) < \infty$, using Egorov's Theorem and absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral.
However, is it still true if:

$\mu(A) = \infty$ and $A$ is $\sigma$-finite? The difficulty here is that (2) does not necessarily hold over the finite measure subsets which cover $A$.
$\mu(A) = \infty$ and $A$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Proofs/counter-examples for the two cases above are welcome.

See my answer to the question  Using Fatou's Lemmas in proving Scheffe's Lemma Part (ii)

Thank you, I could not find the right keywords to search for this question.
